# Parsing RSS in JS without tierce service (vanilla JS or Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rss, firefox-os

I want to recover an RSS feed in JS.

I looked-up on the web a whole day, and found that nearly everybody use google feed API, Yahoo API, or a nodejs/php page for the computing and Jsonification. And I don't want to depend on a service like Google Feed API.

My goal is to fetch an RSS feed, and then create an array where each article on the feed will be an object, in full javascript.

I'm using Angular JS, so if the help could use the benefits of this lib, it would be great, but I'm not closed to any vanilla-JS code if needed.

*For those who may want to ask why : it is for a Firefox OS appliaction, and that's why I can't have any php/nodejs. All have to be made in JS.*

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pople who took the time to answer me :)
It appears it is not really possible without any server computing.

I have to confess that I'm pretty lucky, because the service I wanted to call have just realesed a new API, so happy end for me :)

Thanks every body !

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem to make fetching of xml structure directly?

I think using systemXHR permission regular AJAX request should work fine for you.

Then you'll be able to get from xml what you need in apy possible way.

Answer (score 0):

So my best guess would to just use normal [DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), and then query the document:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
```

I think nowadays you can also use things like `querySelectorAll` to quickly iterate over the document, similar to normal DOM. E.g. something like this would work:

```
[].forEach.call(xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('item'), function(item) {
    console.log(item.querySelector('title').textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't fetch and parse XML feeds on the client without using a 3rd party service because of browser's Same Origin Policies.

From there, there are 2 options:

- fetch and parser on the server side. You'll have to do all the grunt work by your self, but then you can easily load the data from the browser, because it will be under the same domain and hence the Same Origin Policy won't apply
- compromise on your requirement to not use a 3rd party and use one that transforms the XML feeds into JSON to circumvent the SOP.

In both cases, I suggest you check [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) (which I created!), which I believe can help a lot... we also have an [Angular module for feeds](http://blog.superfeedr.com/angularjs-superfeedr/).